# Magento: Referencing a custom block does not work

Tags: magento, layout, module

I'm trying to reference a block from an other custom module to add a child block via layout file but it does not work.

The first layout file contains

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="tabcontainer" as="tabcontainer"
            template="store/tabcontainer.phtml" >
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="kitparts"
                template="store/product/kitparts.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and in the second one I try to reference the `tabcontainer` block

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="tabcontainer">
        <block type="productshippinginfo/productshipping" name="productshippinginfo"
            template="productshippinginfo/productshipping.phtml" after="kitparts"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

but the `productshippinginfo` block is not displayed while it is definitely included in the layout (using Alan Storm's layoutviewer plugin). If I reference `content` it is displayed.

What is wrong? Isn't it possible to add a child to a custom block from a custom extension?

Thanks for your help!

(I'm using Magento 1.6.1.0)

[edit]
in tabcontainer.phtml I'm calling `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: Thank you [Vinai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485589/vinai)!

Adding a dependency to control the loading order of my plugins it works!

in File: app/etc/modules/Company_ContentModule.xml

```
<Company_ContentModule>
  <active>true</active>
  <codePool>local</codePool>
  <depends>
    <Company_ContainerModule />
  </depends>
</Company_ContentModule>
```

So the content module is loaded after the container module.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You just need to add this to you `store/tabcontainer.phtml` file:

getChildHtml('productshippinginfo'); ?>

The reason blocks that are children of "content" render without a template change is that the "content" block is a `core/text_list` block.  If you look in `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`, you will see that in its rendering method (`_toHtml()`) it renders its children.

You could also add an empty `getChildHtml()` call to your `tabcontainer` template to achieve a similar effect as a `core/text_list` - in fact, if you use `getChildHtml('',false,true);` you'll get the sorted children (set with `before=""` and `after=""` params).

---

**EDIT:** adjusted the getChildHtml() call syntax based on OP's comment correct findings that the first param *must* be an empty string a/o/t a boolean.

Comment: I don't want to add getChildHtml('productshippinginfo') because the tabcontainer should take any block that is placed in it (in the future).

Comment: But I'm confused, calling getChildHtml(false,false,true) does not make any output. calling getChildHtml('',false,true) results in the same output than calling getChildHtml(). When I call getChild(), I only get the the kitparts block

Comment: Ah, you are correct. For some reason, there is a strict check on the first param, and it must be an empty string to work as aI suggested. You should use either `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('',false,true) ?>` or `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` if you need the tabcontainer template to echo its children without modification; use the former if you wish to use ordering syntax (before and after).

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that for some reason the `productshippinginfo` block isn't a child of my `tabcontainer` and I cannot access it...

Comment: Things to debug: check system.xml to verify your template is found; turn on developer mode (see index.php /+ .htaccess) and see if your layout file works.

Comment: My template is found, and the layout file works (as mentioned, if I reference `content` the block appears). If I put the `productshippinginfo` block declaration directly in the `tabcontainer` declaration layout file like the `kitparts` block it also works - but I don't want to edit the layout file of my 'store' extension to display any other block from different extensions in my 'tabcontainer'.

Comment: Can't say for sure without debugging, but you have to make sure that your module loads **after** the module that loads the layout file which defines the block you are referencing. Another factor would be the processing order of layout update handles, i.e. you cannot reference a block in the `<default` handle that is being declared in the `<module_controller_action>` handle. This is a general notice, since you are using the same layout update handle. The load order notice still applies, though.

Comment: You can influence the load order by making your module depend on the module that declares the tabcontainer block in the app/etc/modules/*.xml file

Comment: Yay! That's the solution! After adding the dependency in the modules XML file it is working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

In the second layout I think you need to provide the nesting:

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="content">
<reference name="tabcontainer">
    <block type="productshippinginfo/productshipping" name="productshippinginfo"
        template="productshippinginfo/productshipping.phtml" after="kitparts"/>
</reference>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

In order that maganto picks that up

And because you are doing

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

You do not need to specifically call it by name unless you want it to appear in a particular place in your HTML output.

In order to test if your block is appearing in the page at all add output="toHtml" in you block tag.

```
<block type="productshippinginfo/productshipping" name="productshippinginfo"
    template="productshippinginfo/productshipping.phtml" after="kitparts" output="toHtml"/>
```

Comment: Yes, the block is appearing when I add output="toHtml" but unfortunately, nesting the references does not work :(